# shipping_server(5548)_C(5865): Error: data transfer timed out

Tags: clearcase

We are recieving the below error when we are trying to sync the vobs in multisite.

```
2012-10-03T17:12:36+05:30 shipping_server(5548)_C(5865): Error: data transfer timed out
2012-10-03T17:12:36+05:30 shipping_server(5548)_C(5865): Error: unable to forward file
```

We have checked ping telnet everything is working fine , still we are not able to `mkorder` a single test file

Answer (score 0):

Check technote "[Error: data transfer timed out](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21170879)"

> #### Resolving the problem
>
> The number of ports defined on the firewall for MultiSite exchanges will need to be greater than 20 to prevent time-outs.
>
> Increase the number of ports defined in the shipping.conf and firewall to 30 or more.

Other potential causes:

"[How to troubleshoot Shipping Server problems](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21257876)"

It includes:

> Are the ports on both machines open? The server needs at least 3.
> Could there be firewall issues blocking these? For a firewall issue, you may receive the following error:

```
unable to send packet: data transfer timed out
```

And it references technote "[Configuring MultiSite Shipping Server to work within a static port range](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=988&uid=swg21207525)" for other config consideration.